# Overlay not applying to react big calendar

Tags: reactjs, scheduler, react-big-calendar, overlayitem

I'm using react-big-calendar with react-sidebar and if the sidebar opens, all the area is covered by overlay but some elements are visible on the top.
What can be the problem?

P.S: I've also given the z-index to both but nothing worked for me!

[react-big-calendar with react-sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Kxw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particulars of react-sidebar, but it's definitely a z-index issue. Does react-sidebar provide a Portal option for it's overlay (I'm not seeing one)? RBC is dynamically writing out the events to the page, and using 'auto' z-index, so if your overlay is defined first (like the sidebar is on the left, and calendar on the right), then that's what's happening.